# Is it possible to secure the Android KeyChain with an HSM?

Tags: android, android-keystore, hsm

For security reasons I want to store my private key in the HSM and then share the private key with another app via the [`KeyChain`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/KeyChain). The [`KeyStore`](https://source.android.com/security/keystore) mentions that it can be backed by the HSM but I haven't found any documentation that states it's possible with the `KeyChain`.

Based on [the KeyChain documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore), the KeyChain is the proper way to share between apps:

> Use the KeyChain API when you want system-wide credentials. When an
> app requests the use of any credential through the KeyChain API, users
> get to choose, through a system-provided UI, which of the installed
> credentials an app can access. This allows several apps to use the
> same set of credentials with user consent.

So, is it possible to secure the Android KeyChain with an HSM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of searching, I finally found that the answer is yes, it is possible.

The [Android 4.3 changelog](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.3.html#HardwareKeyChain) seems to be the only place that documents it:

> Android also now supports hardware-backed storage for your `KeyChain`
> credentials, providing more security by making the keys unavailable
> for extraction. That is, once keys are in a hardware-backed key store
> (Secure Element, TPM, or TrustZone), they can be used for
> cryptographic operations but the private key material cannot be
> exported. Even the OS kernel cannot access this key material.

---

I tested this with code and it seems that once you import a `KeyPair` into the `KeyChain` it is automatically put into secure hardware. This is the Kotlin code that I ran to test:

```kotlin
GlobalScope.launch {
    context?.let { it1 ->
        val privKey = KeyChain.getPrivateKey(it1, "device_certificate")
        Log.d("App", privKey.toString()) // Shows that this is an AndroidKeyStoreRSAPrivateKey
        val keyFactory: KeyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance(privKey?.algorithm, "AndroidKeyStore")
        val keyInfo: KeyInfo = keyFactory.getKeySpec(privKey, KeyInfo::class.java)
        if (keyInfo.isInsideSecureHardware()) {
            Log.d("App", "The key is in secure hardware!")
        }
        else {
            Log.d("App", "The key is not in secure hardware!")
        }
    }
}
```

which printed "The key is in secure hardware!".